# Something swallows [Left Ctrl] + [Left Shift] + P combination in my Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I tried to use a built in default keyboard shortcut in a software and it was not worked (irrevelant, it was VS Code)

Finally I figured out, that only the [*Left* Ctrl] + [*Left* Shift] + P which is not working, the other three namely:

- [*Left* Ctrl] + [*Right* Shift] + P
- [*Right* Ctrl] + [*Right* Shift] + P
- [*Right* Ctrl] + [*Right* Shift] + P

are working (so my keyboard's left shift is OK)

I went then further and started an other software to see if there is similar issue.
It was Visual Studio 2019, but it does not related to the issue, just diagnostics.
It tried to assign something to [Ctrl]+[Shift]+P, and the left combination does not even recognized. The other three can be assigned... see the attached picture.

**Question**

So something is probably swallowing the [*Left* Ctrl] + [*Left* Shift] + P combination in my Windows system wide. All other letters, for example  are working [*Left* Ctrl] + [*Left* Shift] + A. Also the other three combinations with P also working.

I reviewed all Windows 10 keyboard shortcuts in ms docs, no default binding to [Ctrl]+[Shift]+P...

Any idea what is it?

[image]

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Many thanks for asking. While I was experiencing with Safe Mode, I used an other keyboard, and it turned out the left ctrl + left shift + p with with that keyboard. Ths keyboard exhibits the issue is Hama uRage Cyberboard. If this is a hardware issue, It is really weird, how all other letter combinations with left ctrl + left shift can work...

Comment: So this is a particularity of one keyboard?

Comment: exactly, the Hama uRage Cyberboard, with the other keyboard there is no issue. (I've just seen, my prev comment was not clear, the "works" word left. in the sentence:  "Many thanks for asking. While I was experiencing with Safe Mode, I used an other keyboard, and it turned out the left ctrl + left shift + p **works** with with that keyboard"

Comment: I left an answer, so as not to leave this post without one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question:
Apparently this is a particularity of the Hama uRage Cyberboard.

The problem didn't happen with another keyboard, so is not a problem with Windows.

For some keyboards the firmware can be updated with later versions, but I don't
know if that's the case with this keyboard.

Comment: I have the same exact issue with the  White Shark GK-1925 SPARTAN keyboard.

Comment: I am not alone!

Comment: For me it was Razer Cortex that was causing the issue. Not sure why though, but exiting it solved the problem.
You can also use this keyboard debugger I found. It showed me that only the "Keyup" event fired on `P` when `Ctrl` and `Shift` were down.
https://codepen.io/QDeltaE/pen/PjXWZr

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts not working is usually due to using brand specific devices with companion programs that have overlays. I have a Blackwidow V3 Pro keyboard, and Ctrl+Shift+P is a shortcut for (game) timer reset; it overrides browser private navigation.

You just have to change the shortcut in Razer Cortex  (or other), or close the companion app to fix the issue.